# Can I say "Stars dot the sky"?

Tags: expressions

Can I say "*Stars dot the sky*" when there are lots of stars in the sky? Is it  grammatically correct (the present simple tense)?

Comment: It is prefectly fine.

Comment: The eternal present.

Comment: It is perfectly fine (gelolopez), and rather beautiful.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be correct?

Comment: I didn't relly find anything on Google, that's why I asked, + I wanted to be sure :) 
Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present tense is used for **characteristics, routine, definition** and **description**. So your sentence falls perfectly into present tense use.

The present tense in English is NOT used for something happening at the time the speaker is speaking. We use the present progressive for that. "Stars dot the sky" because that's a perfect description of the sky. It's also a characteristic of stars, that's what they do. Just as "I teach" is what teachers do, it's their job, it's also a routine.

Answer (score 1):

As, the comments say, it is fine.  My guess is that you are worried about using present simple tense because the stars are always in the sky.  But this is fine because they continually appear and disappear (each night).  In a more technical sense, stars die and are reborn all the time (on a cosmological scale at least).

Note the verb "dot" does mean appear (from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dot)):

> : to mark (something) with a dot
>
> : to appear at many different places on the surface of (something)
>
> : to put a small amount of something on different parts of (a surface)